# Requesting reference

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given an increasing  sequence of finite sigma algebras $\mathcal{F}_n$ on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and a consistent sequence of probabilities $P_n$ such that $P_{n+1}$ restricted to $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the same as $P_n$, there exists a probability $P$ on $\sigma(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_n)$ such that $P\big|_{\mathcal{F}_n}=P_n$

Where can I find a proof of this statement? What tools do I need to prove it?

Comment: Where did you find this statement? What do you mean by "consistent"?

Comment: Ikeda and watanake’s stochastic differential equations 1981.Chapter 1 where he talks about regular conditional probabilities